# Angular: Controller-function in ng-if/ng-show doesn't get evaluated again when values changes

Tags: angularjs

My Angular app has a simple controller and a template. The template has  three text inputs. I want to show/hide an based on all three values being set (or not). Now what I experienced so far:

If I use a controller function to check the values, something like

```
ng-if="myCtrl.checkValues()"
```

and the function in the controller is defined as

```
vm.checkValues = checkValues;

function checkValues() {
     return vm.inputVal1 !== '' && vm.inputVal2 !== '' && vm.inputVal3 !== '';
}
```

Then I would expect it to be evaluated every time I update one or more of the values via entering something in the input fields. But it doesn't work. It only works if I don't use a function to check the values but use the functions line of code directly inside the ng-if. It seems that that the function is not being updated every time the values it checks are being changed, is that the case? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing your second `&&` in your check... Not sure what `vm.inputVal2 !== '' vm.inputVal3 !== '';` is doing...

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo, not an actual error in my code. ;-)

Comment: I would suggest using a watcher on that values and perform your if validation according to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try return this expression:

```
$scope.checkValues = function() {
    return ($scope.input1 && $scope.input2 && $scope.input3);
  }
```

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rO1GgkiF9lLEBrDCH31s?p=preview) for you

Comment: Thats basically the same code, just without the preferred ControllerAs-Syntax... Strange that it works with that. Oo But thanks! I

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you want correctly, you want to show/hide some element based on the 3 inputs and whenever the textboxes changes you want to update the hide/show element.

You can do that using ng-change and ng-show, here's an example, not tested but I hope it helps and gives you an idea:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text1" ng-change="checkValues()/>
<input type="text" ng-model="text2" ng-change="checkValues()/>
<input type="text" ng-model="text3" ng-change="checkValues()"/>

<label ng-show="checkValues()">Test</label>

$scope.checkValues = function() {
    return $scope.text1 !== '' && $scope.text2 !== '' && $scope.text3 !== '';
}
```

Comment: Actually in the plunkr i dont need the ng-change. Strange thing is that in my productive code it doesnt work as it does here....

Comment: @Vortilion in your production code you are doing `ctrl.checkValues` not `scope.checkValues`

Comment: Yes, so? It is correct that way cause im using the ControllerAs-Syntax, as I've written.